# Is using ELSE bad programming?

Tags: self-improvement, programming-practices, security

I've often come across bugs that have been caused by using the `ELSE` construct.  A prime example is something along the lines of:

```
If (passwordCheck() == false){
    displayMessage();
}else{
    letThemIn();
}
```

To me this screams security problem.  I know that passwordCheck is likely to be a boolean, but I wouldn't place my applications security on it. What would happen if its a string, int etc?

I usually try to avoid using `ELSE`, and instead opt for two completely separate IF statements to test for what I expect.  Anything else then either gets ignored OR is specifically handled.

Surely this is a better way to prevent bugs / security issues entering your app.

How do you guys do it?

Comment: What is the security problem for you? What does "passwordCheck" mean? There was a password check? There needs to be a password check? The user has passed? The user has failed to enter the right password?

Comment: This is just example code, based on what I've seen.  I was thinking password check would return true or false based on if the password is correct, but perhaps not the best example

Comment: `I know that passwordCheck is likely to be a boolean...` What do you mean? In any strong-typed language. `passwordCheck` will be whatever **you** want it to be.

Comment: I think bad indentation practices lead to more errors than using `else` statements...

Comment: I think that this only works in weakly-typed languages, strongly-typed languages would always return a `bool` no matter what happened within the function. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: "Anything else then...gets ignored" sounds like a much bigger risk to me.

Comment: Just make sure you don't use dynamic typing and the problem is solved.

Comment: I think this was asked before but I can't find it.

Comment: @bigown - I seem to remember a similar one regarding "switch" in place of "else" (if that helps you at all).

Comment: This seems odd.  First, you complain about the possible return type of `passwordCheck()` possibly not being boolean (which may be a reasonable concern), and then you blame it on `else`?  I don't see what problems the `else` causes.

Comment: Programming in functional languages is not equal to bad programming, and for every `if` in a purely functional program, there is always an `else`.

Comment: You could probably also write that `If (passwordCheck() != true)` or `If (!passwordCheck() == true)` or even `If (!passwordCheck())`

Comment: You should be using a language that doesn't let you mix types, if you care about security.

Comment: mmm, i think asking if using else is bad programming is bad programming

Comment: reminds me of a colleague that claimed that "or" was bad because it shows you are not really considering all the possibilities and are combining several of them into one

Comment: @gablin - As a C# programmer enforced indentation is one bit of envy that I have for Python. At least we have nice static analysis tools though like StyleCop.

Comment: How the hell are any of these answers getting upvotes. Especially the one i downvoted. Personally i think the only right answer is Matthieu M. answer and only his. (mine too obviously but his answer is shorter very clear). This thread is unbelievable. Its *almost* as bad as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285864/why-is-net-faster-than-c-in-this-case

Comment: This is *not*, NOT, a typing problem. This is a bad programming problem.

Comment: wow, that text bring back memories. old problems on not server-side programming, good times.

Comment: Most dynamically-typed languages that might auto-cast that to a boolean have a strict equality operator, usually `===`. That's the real problem here, not `else`.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The `else` block should always consist of what you want the default behaviour to be.

There's no need to avoid them, just be careful to use them appropriately.

In your example, the default state should be to not allow access. A little refactoring leaves you with:

```
If (passwordCheck)
{
   letThemIn();
}
else
{
   displayMessage();
}
```

i.e. if the password check works, let them in, otherwise it's always valid to show some error message.

You can of course add additional checks to you logic by using `else if` rather than completely separate `if` statements.

Comment: Yea this is what I tend to go with.  Although much of the code I read defaults it to the other way around - which I believe is a security issue

Comment: @dave.b in the context of the example, I guess it would be a security issue, but if this is all over the place in the code base you're looking at, it's more a sign of whoever wrote it needing a bit more practice :)

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the security aspect of this?  if(!something){do a}else{do b} versus if(something){do b}else{do a} is logically equivalent no?  I am trying to understand what the difference is in terms of security of this?

Comment: @Chris: I think the OP uses a weakly-typed language. Therefore `passwordCheck` could be anything, f.e. `null`, which would render `passwordCheck == false` to `false` and would the user allow to login because of an internal error.

Comment: @Chris, my understanding was that the default state was to allow access, which is not necessarily advisable.

Comment: Yes, this is very language dependent.  In C#, where `if` requires a `bool`, variables must be definitely assigned, all paths must return a value, etc., I cannot think of any reason the order of `if` and `else` would matter besides readability.  That is, `if(a){b();}{c();}` should be equivalent to `if(!a){c();{b();}`.  In JavaScript, on the other hand, you have to be aware that `passwordCheck` could be `undefined`, etc.

Comment: Humm. I've always read that usual case should be in the `if` block and the rare case in the `else` block (invert the boolean if needed to accomplish that) in order to count as "good, readable style". But of course, the only real solution is to be careful.

Answer (score 58):

No, there is nothing wrong with `ELSE`. `ELSE` is not the new `GOTO`.
In fact, using two `IF`s instead of `ELSE` can lead to several problems.

Example one:

```
if (this(is(a(very())==complex(check())))) {
   doSomething();
}

if (!this(is(a(very())==complex(check())))) {
   doTheOtherThing();
}
```

You see the copy-paste? It just waits for the day when you change one and forget the other.

Example two:

```
foreach(x in y) {
  if (first_time) {
    first_time = false;
    doSomething();
  }

  if (!first_time) {
    doTheOtherThing();
  }
}
```

As you can see, the second `IF` will also be executed for the first item, because the condition has already changed. In real world programs, such bugs are harder to spot.

Comment: I agree with this. Copy-pasting an `if` statement and inverting its boolean expression just to avoid an `else` -- now _that_ is bad programming! Not only are you duplicating code (_bad_ programming), you're also slowing down performance (if the check is really complicated, you're now doing it twice -- _ba--_ uh, well, you know what they say about premature optimizations nowadays... _not so good_ programing!).

Comment: To be honest that If check should be in a method of its own to return true / false

Comment: Good examples, lets not forget the performance of using 2 if checks versus one if paired with an else.  I would assume in most languages using an if/else will perform better than using two if statements with one using a not on the condition.

Comment: dave.b: sure, but it could start simple and grow slowly; the complex check in my example is here to make the problem more obvious.

Comment: Yup - and don't forget that conditions can have side effects in most languages, and if there's functions in the conditions you really can't tell by looking.

Answer (score 18):

I personally tend to avoid `else` as much I can, but it's not for any *security* problem.

When reading code, nested statements make it harder to follow the logic, because you need to remember which set of conditions will lead there. For this reason, I am a huge fan of early exit:

```
if (checkPassword != OK) { displayMessage(); return; }

letThemIn();
```

This also applies to `for` and `while` loops in which I will use `continue` and `break` whenever it avoids a level of indentation.

Chris Lattner says it better than I do in the [LLVM Coding Standards](http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#hl_earlyexit).

Comment: I agree. "else" creates a mental "fork" and we humans are sequential creatures.

Comment: Fyi, it's called a guard condition

Comment: @Chad: ah thanks, always nice to get name for things :)

Comment: +1. This is the only answer i can stand that has a score of >1. `*writes an answer*`

Comment: I do not try to avoid else as such, but I think I agree with what you write. The point is that the thing you are testing should be the exception and not the normal case (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them/223881#223881). Here authentication failure is the exception and (only) that should be tested.

Comment: If you avoid `else` I'd suggest you stay away from languages like Haskell...

Comment: @Just: Haskell (and functional languages) don't allow early return since it doesn't fit the "every statement yields a result" mindset, so it obviously does not apply.

Comment: @Matthieu: Erlang is a functional language and doesn't have an else for its `if`.  ;)

Comment: @Just: I don't know Erlang, from what I had read on Haskell I assumed that functional languages were implemented with all expression yielding a result so I guess it's not the case in Erlang.

Comment: Oh, no.  Erlang is no different in that regard.  It's just that there's no "else".  If expressions, however, do always yield results (or there's a nasty error raised).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I actually came to this question looking for some validation of my hunch that early return yields cleaner code (in Obj-C). However, answering the question depends on the language. In any language that autoboxes stuff to boolean, the `passwordcheck()` could have weird results.

Answer (score 17):

There is always an ELSE. If you write

```
if(foo)
  bar();
```

you actually write

```
if(foo)
{
  bar();
}
else
{
   // do nothing
}
```

Whatever you put in the ELSE-path is your responsibility.

Comment: -1. This answer is too ridiculous. I am not saying its not true. It just misses the point. What the compile generates from your code has nothing to do with coding practices and bugs you write

Comment: The questions was "Is using ELSE bad programming?". My answer is: you can pretend it's not there, but not avoid it.

Comment: what language ? in Java the else is not in the bytecode :P

Comment: @acidzombie24 - it's very good practice to consider what the 'else'  is from any question. Sometimes it's just - do everyhtign else in the fucntion, but it does show you have thought about it

Answer (score 5):

Then just replace them,

```
If (passwordCheck == true)
{
     letThemIn();
}
else
{
     displayMessage();
}
```

Comment: How about `If ((passwordCheck == true) == true)` ? :-)

Comment: Well it's my style, to improve readability. You may write if(!value) but i prefer if(value != true)

Comment: It doesn't improve readability. It just adds noise. Even worse are programmers who write nested if constructs just because they're scared of the Boolean operators.

Comment: If the variable name is descriptive, there's no reason why: if (someBooleanValue == true) should be necessary.  This would be better: if (validPassword) {...

Comment: Well i just replaced the code blocks within the question. If you read my first comment i said that i prefer using if(value!=true) instead of if(!value). I hope you can see the difference between if(value) and if(!value). I meant i don't use complement operator. Otherwise you are right, true means true.

Comment: @Ahmet: Just because something has a truth value of false doesn't mean that it is false.  You can get into trouble with things like that in some programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with using ELSE. However it can lead to overly complex code that is hard to read and understand. It may indicate a bad design. It certainly indicates additional use cases that will need to be tested.

Try to remove ELSEs if you can - but don't be paranoid about it. Steve McConnell calls this straight line code in Code Complete. I.e. there is a simple clear path through your code.

Approachs to try for your particular problem:

- use polymorphism. At the boundary to your system validate the security credentials of the user. If they are legitimate then return a session object - with access to the relevant parts of the system or throw an exception. However this could make you system more complex. So you decide what's easier to understand and maintain.

In general - the following may help to reduce ELSEs in your code:

- good requirements may reduce the need for such decisions in the code. You may not need to implement the use case (else) at all.
- clearer design. Maximum cohesion and minimize coupling. This ensures components are not duplicating decisions made in other components.
- exception handling to manage error cases.
- polymorphism (see example above).
- switch statements - these are glorified ELSEs but are better in certain situations.

Comment: I would also include "Move complex boolean checks into a separate function".

Answer (score 3):

Like Matthieu M., I prefer early exit to deeply nested else blocks... It illustrates well defensive programming (if bad conditions, no point to continue). Lot of people will disagree with us, preferring a unique exit point; it is not the point of the debate (I think).

Now, I certainly use `else` when it makes sense, particularly for simple, short alternatives. As said, duplicating the test is a waste of time (programmer's and CPU's), a source of confusion and, later, of bugs (when one is changed, not the other).
Sometime, I add a comment on the `else` part, reminding what was the condition (particularly if the `if` part is long, eg. in legacy code) or what is the alternative.

Note that some extreme proponents of functional programming propose to get rid entirely of `if`, in favor of pattern matching... A bit too extreme for my taste. :-)

Comment: as a side note: if you have an if construct in your pure functional language, then you really need to have an else. Every expression has to return something!

Answer (score 2):

Your supposition about the code being a security leak may or may not be true *depending on the language* you are using.  In C code it could be a problem (particularly because in C a boolean is just an int that is non-zero or zero)--but in most strongly typed languages (i.e. runtime type checking) if the `passwordCheck` variable was declared as a boolean, there is no way to assign something else to it.  In fact, everything in an `if` predicate must resolve to a boolean, whether you use the boolean operators or simply use the value.  If you managed to have another type of object bound to `passwordCheck` the runtime would throw some type of illegal cast exception.

Simple if/else constructs are much easier to read than if/if constructs--and less prone to inadvertant problems if someone tries to flip the construct.  Let's take the same example for a second:

```
if(passwordCheck == false) {
    denyAccess();
}

if(passwordCheck) {
    letThemIn();
}
```

The meaning of the mutually exclusive clauses you want to execute above is lost.  That's what the if/else construct conveys.  Two mutually exclusive branches of execution, where one of them will always run.  This is an important part of security--ensuring there is no way to `letThemIn` after you've called `denyAccess`.

For the purpose of code clarity, and for the purpose of ensuring critical sections are most protected, they should be inside the primary clause (the `if` part).  The default non-compliant behavior should be in the alternate clause (the `else` part).  For example:

```
if(passwordCheck) {
    letThemIn();
} else {
    denyAccess();
}
```

NOTE: in working with different languages, I've developed a coding habbit that does help avoid the question of "what if it's a string?"  Essentially,  it is to put the constant first in the boolean expression.  For example, instead of checking `passwordCheck == false` I am checking `false == passwordCheck`.  This also avoids the accidental assignment problem possible in C++.  Using this approach, the compiler will complain if I type `=` instead of `==`.  In languages like Java and C#, the compiler would treat the assignment in the if clause as an error, but C++ will happily accept it.  That's why I also tend to do null checking with the `null` first.

If you routinely change languages placing the constant first is very helpful.  However, on my team it is opposite the coding standard and the compiler catches those problems anyway.  It can be a hard habbit to break.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that using `else` when programing is bad is like saying that using `otherwise` when speaking is bad.

Sure, they can both be used in bad ways, but that doesn't mean they are to be avoided just because you made a mistake which happened to include them. I wouldn't be surprised if many bugs depended on a missing `default` case in a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `Else` as white-listing your application flow. You check for conditions that SHOULD allow application flow to continue, and if these are not met, then your `Else` is executed to either resolve the problem, discontinue the application execution, or something similar.

`Else` in itself is not bad, but if you use it poorly, you can see undesired effects.

Also, in regards to your statement about

*"I know that passwordCheck is likely to be a boolean, but I wouldn't place my applications security on it."*

For methods that you develop, ALWAYS return one data type. Although PHP Core is littered with code that returns two or more datatypes, this is a bad practice as it makes guesswork of function calls.  If you have to return more than one datatype, consider throwing an exception (I find this is often the reason I would want to return another data type - something went horribly, horribly wrong), or consider re-structuring your code so that you can return only one data-type.

Comment: I didn't know that there were languages that returned more than one datatype! Are you refering to polymorphic functions? I believe whenever I overload a function it has always returned the same datatype, although it may take different arguments.

Comment: In loosely typed languages, and especially in PHP, functions can return more than one data-type. eg: stristr-"Returns the matched substring. If needle is not found, returns FALSE"

Comment: @Michael, A PHP function can return anything you want it to. There's no restriction on the datatype. My most complicated function returns true/false/null, but there's nothing (except common sense) stopping you writing a function which returns true/integer/null/string/float/array.

Comment: Interesting. I've never worked with PHP. Thanks for the explanation though - probably help me in the future! sort of like Javascript then?

Comment: @Michael - Quite similar to Javascript indeed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. LOL! Theres NO REASON to avoid else, at all. Its NOT bad practice in any way, shape or form.

If anything the code should be

```
if(!IsLoggedIn) { ShowBadLoginOrNoAccessPage(); return }
```

Theres no two ifs there and it has no else. This is what i do in all my apps except one in which i throw an exception. The exception is caught in my function which checks the url for the proper page to show (or alternatively i can put the catch/check in asp.net error function). It prints out a generic page that says not authorize or whatever message i use in the exception (i always check the type of exception and set the http status code).

-Edit- as shown in ammoQ example two ifs is ridiculous. *Really* else is just as good or better then an if. If anything ifs are to be avoided (although i personally dont. But i do use return and break a lot) as its been said more code paths increase the likelihood of bugs. See [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#CC)

-Edit 2- If you are worried about if/else usage. I'll also note that my preference is to put the shortest code block at top such as

```
if(cond == false) {
    a()
    b()
    c()
    onetwothree()
}
else
{
    a()
    b()
    c()
    more()
    onetwothree()
    code()
    longer()
}
```

Rather then

```
if(cond) 
{
    a()
    b()
    c()
    more()
    onetwothree()
    code()
    longer()
}
else
{
    a()
    b()
    c()
    onetwothree()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that using branching logic of any kind should be avoided in as much as possible.  While nothing is wrong with ELSE or IF, there are lots of ways to write code to minimize the need to use any branching logic.  I'm not saying branching logic can be totally eliminated--it will be needed in some places--but it is possible to refactor code to eliminate a good chunk of it.  In most cases this will improve the intelligibility and accuracy of your code.

As one example, ternary operators are also usually good candidates:

```
If VIP Then 
  Discount = .25
Else
  Discount = 0
End If
Total = (1 - Discount) * Total
```

Using a ternary approach:

```
Discount = VIP ? .25 : 0
Total = (1 - Discount) * Total
```

Ternary operators shift the branching to the right in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

I like to set a default prior to conditionals when I can. I feel like it's a little easier to read and a bit more explicit, but this is just a preference. I have a tendency to try and avoid negative conditions in my code. I'm not a big fan of checking for !foo or false == foo and I feel like else is kind of the conditional equivalent of a negative.

```
foo = bar;

if ('fubar' == baz) {
    foo = baz;
}
```

instead of ...

```
if ('fubar' == baz) {
    foo = baz;
} else {
    foo = bar;
}
```

The previous code block just seems a little easier for me to read. It seems more natural to me to have a sort of skeptical paranoia about my code. Setting a default regardless of any condition makes me feel comfortable :P